# Random Forest feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest, orange

I am using Random Forest model for feature selection on data with bias. I have tried the Random Forest model on my features by increasing number of trees and found the feature importance moving.

Could anyone help me understand how I should use the 'rfpimp' package in this situation in Orange visual programming?